# How do you work with StrictHostKeyChecking using go.crypto/ssh package in Go?

Tags: ssh, go

So far with the [ssh package](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh) in go I have been able to create some sort of client that will allow two forms of authentication. Either the user inputs a password or it will use keys to authenticate. This works great, however `StrictHostKeyChecking` may be causing an issue. Normally the first time you would SSH into a remote you'll be prompted with a message asking about the host authorization.

Is there anyway in Go to provide the user with that `yes / no` prompt or to disable `StrictHostKeyChecking` altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't implement this for you, but you could provide `HostKeyCallback` in the [`ClientConfig`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh#ClientConfig) struct passed to [`Dial`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh#Dial). The function you provide should validate the hostname and host key against some known list and prompt the user if it doesn't match. The documentation says that the default is to accept all host keys, which is like setting `StrictHostKeyChecking no` in the ssh client config.